# Ansible - ELB - EC2

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible - I am using ansible to add the instances created by ELB ( my AWS will create instances for ELB) to ansible hosts file and access the instances from ansible server. From a linux machine, i use jumpbox and .pem key to access the ec2instance. How will I do in ansible ?

Comment: Please show us (or sketch out) the ansible task(s) you have tried.

Comment: In ansible you need to set AWS key and secret as env variables. E.g. `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='XXXXXXXXXXXX'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='xxxxxxxxx'`

Comment: You can use ansible dynamic inventory for update hostname for new servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in the flag `--private-key=`. You will probably also want to use `-u ec2user` to instruct Ansible to login as the correct user.